# Hovering over a tag in the "merge tags" popup leads to weird behavior around popup sizes

Tags: bug, status-review, design, popups, tag-merge-utility

The merge tags popup contains tags elements. Hovering the mouse over them leads to the tag description popup appearing, but it seems that because one popup (merging) is already opened, the latter popup has the wrong positioning.

For clarification, see the GIF below:

[image]

Screenshot:

[image: "Preview tag rename" showing two tags about to be merged.]

Comment: Yep, I can confirm that I'm able to reproduce the same bug on MSE. (Note: It looks like this bug occurs in Teams as well.)